# Debug boost .ipp files with gdb

Tags: c++, boost, gdb

How do I debug into .ipp files using gdb ?

**UPDATE**

I built boost and client code both with `-g` option.

When I try to debug the code, the TUI mode in GDB just wont let me navigate inside the .ipp files of boost libraries.

This is a real hassle and as a work around, I generated a preprocessed output file from `gcc` option `-E` and renamed it as `New.cpp` file.

This renamed `New.cpp` will have all of the template instantiations (the ones I was trying to navigate in .ipp file) of a particular boost library (e.g. serialization) embedded in it.

I then compiled this `New.cpp` using `-g` and debugged it to see some miracle.

But it still just doesn't navigate to places (template instantiations that are embedded inside `New.cpp`) .

As such I am in dire need to find a way to debug these .ipp files. I hope I have made my intent clear over here.

Comment: What exact problem do you have with debugging .ipp files?

Comment: I can not step into the code in the .ipp file and I can not see any code in TUI mode.

Comment: Do you build code with `-g`?

Comment: Yes I did build my code with `-g`